# iOS 6 - does it save my location?

Tags: security, ios, geolocation

I recently found out that the iPhone keeps (at least on older versions) your location data in a data file:

http://petewarden.github.com/iPhoneTracker/#faq

I have an iPhone on iOS 6 but my consolidated.db doesn't have the CellLocation table. The only table that has Lat / Lon information is Fences, but it's empty.

Has Apple fixed the security hole and stopped recording the data?

UPDATE

I found this article saying that Apple promised to keep the data for a shorter time:

http://www.yourdailymac.net/2011/04/apple-the-iphone-is-not-logging-your-location/

I'd like something more certain about which iOS versions are affected.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found the answer. It was fixed in 4.3.3. Data is only saved for a week, along with other safeguards.

http://www.phonearena.com/news/Apple-to-shortly-release-iOS-4.3.3-update-deals-with-location-tracking-bug_id18571